# String as a file name C#

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have a problem writing a program in C#.

I want to to save string variables from a ListBox1 to textfile, which is named after the item from ListBox2, like here:

```
Write = new StreamWriter(xxxxx);
for (int I = 0; I < ListBox1.Items.Count; I++)
{
    Text = (SubCategories.Items[I]).ToString();
        Write.WriteLine(Text);
}
Write.Close();
```

What should I replace `xxxxx` to have there ListBox2.SelectedItem, for example to make file "test.txt".

Answer (score 4):

You can replace `xxxxx` with this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    for (int I = 0; I < ListBox1.Items.Count; I++)
    {
        Text = (SubCategories.Items[I]).ToString();
        writer.WriteLine(Text);
    }
}
```

*You should use a `using` with `IDisposable` objects.*

Comment: OP Wanted to know how to get the filename from a listbox, not hardcode it.